# Export a function that returns a function

Tags: angular, typescript, function

Still new to Angular...

After researching the documentation and searching the web, I can't seem to figure out how to export a function that returns a function. Trying something like:

```
export function generateValidCharacterGenerator(validCharacters: string): function(control: FormControl): any {
    const result = function (control: FormControl): any {

    };

    return result;
}
```

(I tried this from reading: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html)

But gets syntax errors on everything I try. You can do this, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export var generateValidCharacterGenerator : (validCharacters: string) => (control: FormControl)=> any = (validCharacters: string) => {
    const result = (control: FormControl): any => {
    };
    return result;
}
```

I would recommend you use arrow functions instead of `function` as it preserves `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the word `function` to declare a function as a type in TypeScript.

For example;

```
// this is a function
function foo(): number {
   return 4;
}

// this is a type
type foo = () => number;
```

The arrow function is both a function and a type.

For example;

```js
// this is a function
const foo = () => 4;
```

Arrow functions are a feature of JavaScript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Arrow types are a feature of TypeScript.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

When you write arrows as a type they do not have a function body. The parameters yield a return type, for example: `(a: boolean) => number` takes a boolean and returns a number. When the arrow is a function it has a body and a return type, for example: `(a: boolean): number => 4;`

It depends *where* you use them.